# How to retrieve seller information from Amazon mws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am looking to create an app where I can get seller information through anmazon MWS (MWS integration). The URL I generated is

https://sellercentral.amazon.in/gp/mws/registration/register.html?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJKTFMS3KQ3NL7V6Q&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&id=amzn1.application.674faae88ed840af939732ce704aa955&returnPathAndParameters=https%3A%2F%2Frequestb.in%2Fxxttsixx&Signature=XjHVwiv4o8fHe6/lxqAaTd2Z4FKOcKvDHOwdfpGLf0Q%3D

The id used is "amzn1.application.674faae88ed840af939732ce704aa955". But when i looked up other references, they were of the format, 
"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
which I am not able to figure out anywhere. I guess I am using the wrong app-id.

Similar post in Amazon Forum,
https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=3751728#3751728

This is too not answered.
Any help here would be very much appreciated.

Comment: whatever you are doing there does not look like a MWS call to me. Please try to explain more what you are trying to do and where exactly it fails.

Comment: I have been trying to integrate the "Add Channel" process, where I am trying to make the Seller provide access to their Amazon seller account with MWS.
This is already been implemented in XSellco and app.orderhub.io.

Comment: I am not aware that this can be done through a link. The MWS FAQ only state how to do that manually: https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/faq.html

Comment: The answer that I was looking for is Amazon - Integrated Registration Pipeline(IRP).
Btw, thanks Hazzit.

Comment: @SenthilRaj didn't you make any progress on it? Stuck with the similar issue as well.